# how detect which button was called

Tags: jquery

I have form. I add two button use JQuery. How can I get name of this button?

```
<form id="frm">
</form>
//JQuery:
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest"  value="Preview"/>');
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest1" value="Next"/>'); 
$("#frm").on("click",  function () {
if (this...=="Next")
 {
  alert("It's button Next");
 }else
 {
  alert("It's button Preview");
 }
});
```

Comment: pass in event.  event.target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **DEMO: *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ZCwyX/1/)***

**HTML:**

```
<form id="frm"></form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest"  value="Preview"/>');
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest1" value="Next"/>');
    $("#frm > .btn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).val() == "Next") {
            alert("It's button Next");
        } else {
            alert("It's button Preview");
        }
    });
});
```

### **SIMPLIFIED CODE:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest"  value="Preview"/>');
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest1" value="Next"/>');
    $("#frm > .btn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("It's button " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

### **WITHOUT USING CLASS ATTRITBUTE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ZCwyX/3/)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest"  value="Preview"/>');
    $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest1" value="Next"/>');
    $("#frm > [name^='GoTest']").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("It's button " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

***[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):***

`[attribute^=value]`: All elements with a name attribute value starting with value.

*Updated: To use the child property, please note the e.preventDefault() will stop the auto `POST` of the `FORM` html tag.*

Comment: @user2576078 can you use the `name` property?

Comment: Yes, it is very important to stop the POST request.

Comment: @user2576078 changed to use the name property the `e.preventDefault()` will stop the `POST` request.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you ask for name, but the text "Next" is in the value... So try this:

```
$("#frm").on("click", '.btn',  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.value=="Next")
     {
          alert("It's button Next");
     }else
     {
          alert("It's button Preview");
     }
});
```

If you want to get the name you can use `$(this).prop('name');` inside the click function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).val() == "Next"){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the event delegation syntax of `.on()`:

```
 $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest"  value="Preview"/>');
 $("#frm").append('<input class="btn" type="submit" name="GoTest1" value="Next"/>');

 $('#frm').on('click', '.btn', function () {
     console.log($(this).attr('name'))
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mqJXf/1)**

`$(this).attr('name')` get's the name as you asked for, however if you want the value, use `$(this).val()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#frm").on("click",  function (event) {
if (event.target.attr("value") === "Next")
 {
  alert("It's button Next");
 }else
 {
  alert("It's button Preview");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The *name* of the button is not the same as the *value* of the button.

```
$("#frm").on("click",  function (ev) {
    alert($(ev.currenTarget).prop('name'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the name of the button when it is clicked and then detect which button was clicked.